# How to say "I am keen on sth" in German?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

> ***Ich bin davon sehr begeistert, dass sie das Haus putzen.***
>
> I am very keen about them cleaning the house.
>
> ***Ich bin von Aufräumen des Hauses sehr begeistert.***
>
> I am very keen on cleaning the house.
>
> ***Ich bin davon sehr begeistert, wie sie das Haus aufräumen.***
>
> I am very keen on how they clean the house.

I do not know if you can eliminate *davon* in these cases, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich würde das mit

> Es freut mich sehr, dass sie das Haus putzen.
>   Ich freue mich darüber, dass sie das Haus putzen.

übersetzen. *Begeistern* verwendet man in wirklich außergewöhnlichen Fällen und meistens bezogen auf sich selbst:

> Ich bin begeistert von dieser Aussicht.
>   Das Theaterstück hat mich begeistert.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives without “davon”:

> Es begeistert mich (sehr), dass sie das Haus putzen.
>
> Das Aufräumen des Hauses begeistert mich (sehr).
>
> Es begeistert mich (sehr), wie sie das Haus aufräumen.

For my taste *begeistern* + *sehr* is a little too much enthusiasm, especially when it comes to taking care of the household.

Comment: `dict.leo.org` übersetzt `to be keen on something` auch mit `Lust auf etwas haben` bzw `to be keen to do something` mit `sehr daran interessiert sein etwas zu tun`. Letztere deutsche Bedeutung scheint mir bzgl. Hausputz ja irgendie passender, obwohl das `on` fehlt. Aber das kann natürlich an meiner persönlichen Sicht der Sache liegen ... ;-)